# How do i keep the rest of an array of strings in C from filling with junk?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I'm working on a practice program where the user inputs a list of names. I've got the array of strings set to 50 long to give the user plenty of space, but if they are done, they can type 'quit' to stop typing. how can i keep the rest of the array from filling with junk or possibly shrink it to fit only the entered list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char list[50][11];
   char temp[11];
   int index;

   printf("Input a list of names type 'quit' to stop\n")

   for(index = 0; index < 50; index++)
   {
      scanf(" %10s", temp);

      if(strcmp(temp, "quit") != 0)
      {
         strcpy(list[index], temp);
      } 
      else
      {
         index = 50;
      }
   }

   for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
   {
      puts(list[index]);
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and explain why you need to shrink it or prevent "junk data" after the null-terminator

Comment: There's no harm in junk at the end of an array provided that you don't access it. Arrays in C don't carry length information, so you must store that information alongside the array. There are two common patterns: Keep the actual array length in avariable and write your functions so that the accept the array plus the length. Altenatively, use a sentinel value such as an empty string or a null pointer. That's the way C strings work. In both cases, you must take care not to overflow the size of the array.

Comment: Simply zero initialize everything: `char list[50][11] = { 0 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this is a Zen of Programming question, and UnholySheep is prodding you to think in the right direction.

What is Junk?  You have told the computer you need a list of 50 things, but you didn't tell it what to put in all of those list entries.  So the computer just uses whatever memory it has lying around, and the odds of a particular byte being whatever value you decide is Not Junk is something like 1:256.

Of course, the Zen here is not the answer to the question "What is Junk", but rather understanding that there is Junk and Not Junk, and the only Not Junk is that which you have arranged for to exist.

So, if you don't know that a memory address does not contain Junk, then it does.

The solution to your programming question then, is to keep track of how many list entries are Not Junk. There are two common approaches used in C for this:

1. keep track of the length of your list, or
2. put a special value at the end of your list

Answer (score 0):

> how can i keep the rest of the array from filling with junk (?)

1) Use `index`.  Simply keep track of how much was used.  Do not access the unused portion of the array

```
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      puts(list[i]);
    }
```

2) Mark the next unused with a leading *null character*.

```
    if (index < 50) list[index][0] = '\0';

    for(int i = 0; i < 50 && list[i][0]; i++) {
      puts(list[i]);
    }
```

3) Re-architect: use a right-sized allocation array (below), a link-list, etc.

---

> or possibly shrink it to fit only the entered list (?)

Once an *array* is defined, its size cannot change.

Yet a pointer to an allocated memory can be re-allocated.
Here `list` is a [pointer to array 11 of char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*list%29%5B11%5D+%3B)

```
char (*list)[11] = malloc(sizeof *list * 50); // error checking omitted for brevity
....
// fill up to 50
....
list = realloc(sizeof *list * index);   // error checking omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

just keep a count of entered values

```
   int count = 0;

   printf("Input a list of names type 'quit' to stop\n")

   for(index = 0; index < 50; index++)
   {
      scanf(" %10s", temp);

      if(strcmp(temp, "quit") != 0)
      {
         strcpy(list[index], temp);
          count++;
      } 
      else
      {
         index = 50;
      }
   }

   for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
   {
      puts(list[index]);
   }
```